# Subspace Perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, orthogonality, perturbation-theory

For two positive semidefinite matrices $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, with dominant $r$ dimensional subspaces $U,V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$ and eigenvalues $\Sigma_A, \Sigma_B$, what can we say about the singular values of the matrix
$$
\left(U\Sigma_A^{1/2}\right)^TV\Sigma_B^{1/2} = \Sigma_A^{1/2}U^TV\Sigma_B^{1/2}
$$
in terms of $\|A-B\|_{op}$ or $\|A-B\|_F$ ?